# Angular 2 Route module not imported when using with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am just a beginner with Angular 2. I am trying to build a TODO app using 
Angular 2 with webpack bundeler. I am facing an issue where RouterModule is not loading when trying to implement Angular Component Routing.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ToDoModule } from './todos/todo.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './app-header.component';

const ROUTES: Routes = [{
  path:'home', component: HeaderComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ToDoModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And I have included `router-outlet` in the AppComponent's HTML. But when application loads it throws an error

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'router-outlet' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" -->
>
> [ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@2:0 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
>   'router-outlet' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" -->
>
> [ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@2:0

I did the same app using *System.js* it works fine. Can anyone please help me to figure out the issue? Thanks

Comment: Did you add the `RouterModule` to `imports` in the module that contains the component with the router-outlet?

Comment: Yes .AppModule contains the component with  the router-outlet

Comment: What about the ToDoModule? Does it not contain any router-outlet or routerLink?

Comment: No it doesn't have any router-outlet component

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: Yes.I will try to reproduce it in plunker